# How to Import a File from a different folder in Python

Tags: python, directory, raspberry-pi, python-import, directory-structure

This is my project structure:

- Elvvo

  - functions

    - lights.py
  - main.py

The directory of the Elvvo folder is `/home/pi/Desktop/Elvvo` as I am working on a Raspberry Pi.

I have a couple of functions defined in `main.py`. I want to call those functions from `lights.py`. How do I do this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

### **Technique-1**

You can use the `sys.path.insert()` builtin-method to **insert the path of main.py to position 1 of the system’s path variable**. This ensures that it’s loaded with highest priority and avoids any naming conflicts if present.

Please see how I have solved this below:

My folder structure is as shown below:

```
import_test
├── functions
│   └── function.py
├── main.py
```

My main.py

```
def printFromMainA():
    print("FromMainA")


def printFromMainB():
    print("FromMainB")
```

My functions/function.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "Absolute path to import_test/")

from main import *

def printFunction():
    print("FromFunction")
    printFromMainA()
    printFromMainB()


printFunction()
```

And then finally when I run from `import_test` folder

```
python functions/function.py
```

I get the following output:

```
FromFunctionA
FromMainA
FromMainB
```

### **Technique-2**

You can also use the `sys.path.append()` method which **appends the path of the main.py to the system’s path variable**. This will add the current path to the last position of the system’s paths list.

In this case all you need to do to the function.py is:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("Absolute path to import_test/")

from main import *

def printFunction():
    print("FromFunction")
    printFromMainA()
    printFromMainB()


printFunction()
```

This should also give you the desired output.